# Detect pushed routes on Flutter

Tags: flutter

How can I check if a named route is currently on the stack?
I do not want to build a new route every time the user pushes a named route that already exists.

Also, is there a way to pop a named route?

Something like `Navigator.of(context).popNamed(routeToPop)`

Comment: why do you want `popNamed`? Can you please describe your use case?

Comment: @DineshBalasubramanian , I have a Flutter package (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flushbar) that pushes a route to show a notification to the user. Similar to a Snackbar.
The problem is that when I pop the route to dismiss the notification, it is not guaranteed that it is still the top route, causing some unexpected behavior. I want to be able to pop a specific route at any point in time.

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html allows you to listen to route changes and maintain a copy of the stack yourself where you can look up existing routes.

You can also upvote this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/22408 that exposes the history stack.

Comment: A little unrelated ping: I reopenned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52570015/see-the-stack-of-flutter-navigator?noredirect=1
This question is different from the linked one. The linked is about having a route inspector like the widgets inspector

Comment: I don't see a difference. I think they want the same thing for different reasons.

Comment: If it's about tooling, RouteObserver isn't really convenient to debug the list of routes.

Answer (score 3):

Since in my case I had control over the route instance, I went on to investigate the `navigator` a little further. I found a method that solved my problem:

`navigator.removeRoute(myRoute)`

It does not animate the route out though. The route simply vanishes. For what I need, that is ok since when `removeRoute` is called, the route to be removed is hidden anyway.