# See the stack of Flutter Navigator

Tags: flutter

During execution, is there a way for the developer to see the state of the Navigator stack?

I am using Visual Studio Code and Android Studio.

For instance:

```
Navigator 
RouteA
RouteB
RouteD
etc.
```

Comment: If you use Android studio, you could inspect the Navigator using the widget inspector. And look for it's internal history (not sure if it's visible from the IDE, but it's an idea)

Comment: @RémiRousselet You are right: I can see the Navigator in the Android Studio Widget Inspector (screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/rYFZjqH). I can se the NavigatorState but not the routes stack unfortunately. Unless I'm looking in the wrong place..

Answer (score 36):

Following steps:

1. Set a breakpoint where you want to inspect, which must be inside a `builder` function which has `context`, and run in Debug mode
   [image]
2. Run your app to the break point
3. Open "Evaluate expression"
   [image]
4. Evaluate `Navigator.of(context)`
   [image]
5. Inspect the `_history`[image]

In my example, you can see there are 2 routes in the history, with all relevant debuggable data.

Hope it helps

Comment: On Windows and VS Code, steps 3 & 4 look a little different. Just type `Navigator.of(context)` into the DEBUGGER CONSOLE at the bottom of your screen. Then proceed with step 5. (I'm new to debugging so this might be wrong.)