# Flutter navigate to a certain screen from any screen

Tags: flutter

How do i able to navigate back to main screen from any screen. I try draw some example below.

```
runApp() ->HomePage()
           ->FirstScreen()
             ->FirstSubScreen() // <- Back to HomePage
           ->SecondScreen()
           ->ThirdScreen()
```

What i'm trying to achieve is, when i'm at the `FirstSubScreen` i can navigate back to `HomePage`. I've tried using `onPressed: () => Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/homepage')` but nothing happen, no error or anything. So how do i able to solve this problem? I will include some codes.

**main.dart**

```
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

String username = '';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: LoginPage(),
  routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    '/landingpage': (BuildContext context) => new MyApp(),
    '/homepage': (BuildContext context) => new HomePage(
          username: username,
        ),
  },
);
}
}
```

In login page, i'm social login after successful signed in, it navigate to `HomePage()`

In home page, i'm using tab controller with 3 tabs, `FirstScreen`,`SecondScreen`,`ThirdScreen`. In `FirstScreen` i have scan button that after successful scan, it will navigate to `FirstSubScreen`, below are the codes.

**FirstScreen.dart**

```
Future scan() async {
try {
  String barcode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
  setState(() {
    var parsedJson = jsonDecode(barcode);
    var qrdetails = QRDetails.fromJson(parsedJson);
    final data = QRDetails(
      name: "${qrdetails.name}",
      type: "${qrdetails.type}",
      amount: "${qrdetails.amount}",
    );

    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => ScannedScreen(
                  barcodedata: data,
                )));
  });
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
    setState(
        () /* {
      this.barcode = 'The user did not grant the camera permission!';
    } */
        {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: 'You need to grant the camera permission',
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    });
  } else {
    setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
  }
} on FormatException {
  setState(
      () /* => this.barcode =
      'null (User returned using the "back"-button before scanning anything. Result)' */
      {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: 'Scan canceled', toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
  });
} catch (e) {
  setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
}
}
```

**FirstSubScreen**

```
Widget backtoMainButton() {
return Align(
    alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
    child: Container(
        height: 80.0,
        child: SizedBox.expand(
          child: FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('/homepage'));
            },
            child: Text('BACK TO HOME',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    fontFamily: "Roboto Regular",
                    color: Colors.black)),
          ),
        )));
}
```

Comment: Can you try to follow this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55408873/3266152) and see the stack as a way to assure that '/homepage' is in your stack? Because if it isn't then it might be the reason you cannot `popUntil`. I am simply guessing, but please try it out.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering, before i try that approach that you suggest, is my code for navigating correct? From `main.dart` to `FirstScreen.dart` then to `FirstSubScreen.dart`, i've been debugging for so long and couldn't solve.