# How can we check if a route exists in the navigation stack?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to check if a specific route exists in the navigation stack or not, so that if it exists use `popUntil` to navigate to that page and not generate a duplicate route in the stack and if not exists, push a new route for that specific page.

is there any way to check the existence of a specific route?

I tried the code below:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
        TradePage.routeName, (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

to push a new route and remove any other route in the stack, **but I shouldn't generate a new route if it exists in the stack**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52569224/14231239) you can refer to [Route Observer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html)
Another way of doing this is to save your routes names in a List held by a global variable. So each time you want to push to a new page, you can check if the page name is not in your list